# Android and XML maps

Tags: android, xml, dictionary

Can you create an XML object resource with key-value pairs (basically a hashmap) using an XML file analogous to arrays.xml? This would be an analogue of NSDictionary from Obj-C.

i.e.

```
<key>foo</key>
<value>bar</value>
```

I'd like for the value to be an array of strings, and I'd like to be able to copy and paste from XML files in my Obj-C projects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative is to create JSON objects, and access these using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). If you already have a PList resource from an iPhone project, one way to convert to JSON is to create an object from the PList and write it to a JSON string file.